# Why is Playwright closing the page so early?

Tags: javascript, playwright

I am trying to record a video of a set of CSS transitions that I have mode work like the opening title sequence.  I got a simpler test with a single rotating cube working on my macbook laptop.

I have set up a single `index.html` with all the css and html needed to do my transitions.  Standalone in Chrome Browser it works fine.

I am now working on my linux (Debian) with the same configuration but a bigger set of transitions that take about 45 seconds to run.  I want to record 50 seconds of video.

However running it under `nodejs`/`playwright` I find playwright is closing the page prematurely - how do I find out why?

The code driving playwright

```
const { chromium } = require('playwright');  // Or 'firefox' or 'webkit'.


(async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch();
console.log('got browser')
  const context = await browser.newContext({
    recordVideo: {
      dir: './videos',
      size: {
        width:1920,
        height:1080
      }
    },
    viewport: {
      width:1920,
      height:1080
    }

  });
console.log('got context')
  const page = await context.newPage();
  const start = new Date().getTime();
  page.on('close', () => {
    const closetime = new Date().getTime();
    console.log('page close occurred after', closetime - start, 'ms');
  });
console.log('got page');
  await page.goto('http://localhost:8000/index.html',{timeout: 0});
console.log('page loaded')
  await new Promise(accept => setTimeout(accept, 50000));

const timeouttime = new Date().getTime();
  console.log('timeout complete after', timeouttime - start, 'ms');
  await browser.close();
console.log('browser closed');

})();
```

and the results as show in the console

```
got browser
got context
got page
page loaded
page close occurred after 2254 ms
timeout complete after 50152 ms
browser closed
```

As can be see the page (to my mind) randomly closes after about two seconds, whereas I am assuming it could run for 50 seconds.

WHY is Playwright closing the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  On of the elements on my page was using the css property
`filter: blur(1em);`

This was causing the page to close in playwright as soon as it was encountered.  I ended up using `box-shadow` (with an inset and normal outside shadow) and opacity a low `opacity` to cause a similar effect and the problem went away.